# Is there a possibility to display regions in a detailed map (instead of cities)?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to display the map of Italy using HighMaps and geoJson data.

I have setup a default display of the map here:

[JSFiddle Italy Map](https://jsfiddle.net/LucaLibralato/me9g2onh/)

Using default settings, the map will display all Italian cities (provinces), but I have noticed that (within the source code of the map) Italian regions are also available, for example:

```
"region":"Campania"
```

Would it be possible to set some options to display regions (grouping provinces in regions) instead of cities?

As a final result, I'd like to get a map displaying the 20 Italian regions, and then of course displaying some data for each region.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/italy-regional-map-template/

In the below demo, I prepared an example with code how to set data to above map.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8se6p14w/

Code to parse data:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load() {
      this.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
        data.forEach(d => {
          if (d[0] === p.name) {
            p.update({
              value: d[1]
            }, false)
          }
        })
      })
      this.redraw()
    }
  }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, thank you very much for taking the time to reply my question. I have currently implemented exactly the map you suggested: https://covid.lucalibralato.com
I was just curious to know if there was the possibility to use the full map and just use the "region" properties to render the map at region level, because that would have been really powerful to be able to switch between regions and provinces easily. Thank you very much for your help, currently it's my preferred method.

Comment: Very nice data visualization. I like it!

Comment: Thank you very much again for your help.